# Can a neural network be trained on a dataset containing only values for true output for a classification problem?

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning, classification, datasets, data-preprocessing

I am using a dataset from Google which contains 1,27,000 data points on simulated concentrations of the atmosphere of exoplanets which can sustain life. So, the output label of all these data points is 1 i.e, probability of life existing there is 1. If I train my neural network on this data, and test it on data points with concentrations other than these, can I expect to get probability values at the output? Asking because the model knows no false labelled value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can and the answer is **One-Class Classification**. A well-written resource to understand is [this](https://machinelearningmastery.com/one-class-classification-algorithms/).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I will check it out.